# Iterate through to create a hash of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

As the final result I need a hash like:

```
{items: {lorem: val1, dolor: val2}, {lorem: val1, dolor: val2}...}
```

e.g. a hash of hashes.

Put the problem is it should be created from iteration like this:

```
@result = []

@goods = {lorem: "ipsum", dolor: "sit"}

@items.each do |item|
  @goods.map do |k, v|
    if item.title == "ipsum"
      @result << [k, v]
    else
      @result << [k, item.title]
    end
  end
end
```

But this is not what I'm searching for, as @result is Array, and it's not 2-dimensional (as result i have [[foo, bar] [foo1,bar1]...])

I see how `k` could be converted to Hash key (k.to_sym), but my problem is to have Hash of hashes as the final output.

Ruby 1.9.3 (and Rails, but I believe this could be done without any Rails additions)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of the expected result is not a valid Hash.

Instead of

```
{items: {lorem: val1, dolor: val2}, {lorem: val1, dolor: val2}...}
```

It should be like this

```
{items: [{lorem: val1, dolor: val2}, {lorem: val1, dolor: val2}]}
```

It's also not hard to get the result you want

```
@items = []
@goods = {lorem: "ipsum", dolor: "sit"}
@items << @goods
@result = {items: @items}
```